# How do I select an element in a complex JSON array in java

Tags: java, json

I can't seem to get the selection of elements in the array right. Or the syntax swears or something else. Here is what I am trying

```
{
    "info": "info",
    "user":[{
        0: 
            "info":{
                "name": "user 1"
            }

    }]

}
```

Here is my code and what i am trying to do

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
System.out.println(jsonObject.getJSONArray("user").getJSONArray(0).getJSONArray("info").getString("name"));
```

And I don't get anything. Who can tell me how to do it right

Comment: Which JSON handling library is this exactly? There are dozens

Comment: i use
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: In that case I think you have one step wrong in your method chain: `getJSONArray("info")` should be `getJSONObject("info")`

Comment: yes, in my json_string line json "{"info" .......}"

Comment: And I'm pretty sure `.getJSONArray(0)` yields `{
        0: 
            "info":{
                "name": "user 1"
            }

    }` so directly calling `.getJSONArray("info")` on that will probably fail, too

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke, how to do it right. Can you suggest)
just started working with Java, it was easy on powershell a lot ;D

Comment: I did it like this, but swears at this part for some reason
 `jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("info");`

error  `getJSONObject(0)`

Comment: Did a bit of checking. The JSON snippet you provided isn't valid JSON (according to jsonlint.com), so it's unparseable as is.

Comment: Now the skin is exact JSON
`{
  "user":[
     {
       "info":{
         "name": "info"
       }
     }
  ]
}`

Comment: Alternatively, you could also write a class for the json structure and use Gson to parse the object

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone. I figured out how to do it here is the code)

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray userArray = obj.getJSONArray("user");
        JSONObject userInfo = userArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("info");
        String reciver = userInfo.getString("name");
```